# Can all differential equations be solved using power series?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, power-series

To elaborate, does the differential equation have to be of some form to be solvable by power series.  More specifically, if I wanted to solve this equation by power series would I be able to?
$$
(1-x^2)y''(x)-3xy'(x)+n(n+2)y(x)=0
$$
Also, $n$ is a constant in the stated equation.

Comment: Please try to use mathjax/LaTeX for the formulas, in this level it is simple to do.

Comment: Thanks, I will keep that in mind for the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(1-x^2)y''(x)-3xy'(x)+n(n+2)y(x)
=0
$

I'll try
$y(x)
=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} a_k x^k
=a_0+a_1x+\sum_{k=2}^{\infty} a_k x^k
$.

$y'(x)
=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} ka_k x^{k-1}
=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (k+1)a_{k+1} x^{k}
$
so
$xy'(x)
=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (k+1)a_{k+1} x^{k+1}
=a_1x+\sum_{k=2}^{\infty} ka_{k} x^{k}
$.

$y''(x)
=\sum_{k=2}^{\infty} k(k-1)a_k x^{k-2}
=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (k+1)(k+2)a_{k+2} x^{k}
$
so

$\begin{array}\\
(1-x^2)y''(x)
&=(1-x^2)\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (k+1)(k+2)a_{k+2} x^{k}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (k+1)(k+2)a_{k+2} x^{k}
-x^2\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (k+1)(k+2)a_{k+2} x^{k}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (k+1)(k+2)a_{k+2} x^{k}
-\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (k+1)(k+2)a_{k+2} x^{k+2}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (k+1)(k+2)a_{k+2} x^{k}
-\sum_{k=2}^{\infty} (k-1)ka_{k} x^{k}\\
&=2a_2+6a_3x
+\sum_{k=2}^{\infty} ((k+1)(k+2)a_{k+2}-(k-1)ka_{k}) x^{k}\\
\end{array}
$.

Adding these all up

$\begin{array}\\
0
&=(1-x^2)y''(x)-3xy'(x)+n(n+2)y(x)\\
&=n(n+1)(a_0+a_1x)-3(a_1x)+2a_2+6a_3x
+\sum_{k=2}^{\infty} x^k\left(   n(n+2)a_k-3ka_{k}+((k+1)(k+2)a_{k+2}-(k-1)ka_{k})\right)\\
&=n(n+1)a_0+2a_2+x(n(n+1)a_1-3a_1+6a_3)
+\sum_{k=2}^{\infty} x^k\left(   (n(n+2)-3k-k(k-1))a_k+(k+1)(k+2)a_{k+2})\right)\\
&=n(n+1)a_0+2a_2+x(n(n+1)a_1-3a_1+6a_3)
+\sum_{k=2}^{\infty} x^k\left(   (n(n+2)-k(k+2))a_k+(k+1)(k+2)a_{k+2}\right)\\
\end{array}
$

Therefore,
assuming no errors
($P(\text{no errors}) < 1-1/e)$),

$0
=n(n+1)a_0+2a_2
$,

$0
=(n(n+1)-3)a_1+6a_3
$,

and

$0
= (n(n+2)-k(k+2))a_k+(k+1)(k+2)a_{k+2}
$.

These recurrences
show how to compute
the $a_k$
in terms of
$a_0$ and $a_1$.

Note that
$y(x)$ is the sum of
two independent series,
one with even exponents
and one with odd.

The last recurrence has
an obvious problem
at $k=n$,
so LutzL's suggestion
of multiplying the series
by $x^{\alpha}$
might have to be done.

I'll leave it at this.

Comment: Could you have started the sum for y' and y'' from 0 instead of 1 and 2, respectively?

Comment: Yes, but the omitted terms are zero, so nothing would have changed. Also, the series for y' and y'' do stuff for 0 and 1, so, since I wanted a sum for k for all 3 series, I needed to start at 2.

Comment: You got 3 recurrence relationships using your method.  I got only 1 when I started the sums from 0.  Did I loose information by starting my sums at 0?

Comment: Actually,  pnly the last is a recurrence. My terminology was wrong.

Answer (score 3):

If the differential equation is analytical, then one can try to find local solutions as power series.

However, in points of singularity, here in $x=\pm1$, one may have to multiply the power series by a fractional power, giving Puisseux-series as solutions.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  By analytical do you mean the differential equation should not blow up locally?.

Comment: No, that's a contradiction, you can always restrict the domain so that it does not contain the singularity. The solution of an ODE is one order better than the ODE itself, So if the ODE is $C^k$, then the solution is $C^{k+1}$, if the ODE is $C^\infty$, then also the solution, if the ODE is analytical, then also the solution.